# how I can make an indicator for age interval?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to make some indicators for each age interval. For example let I need 4 indicators I1,I2,I3,I4 corresponding the following intervals:

```
  age
 6-18
 19-30
 30-60
 +60
```

Now suppose I have the following data and so the indicators must be like this:

```
age    I_1   I2   I3   I4
 24     0     1    0    0
 10     1     0    0    0
 50     0     0    1    0
```

then

Comment: Question isn't clear. Maybe give a better example.

Comment: @Suren plz see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(24, 10, 50))
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(`6-18` = 1* (age > 6 & age <= 18), 
              `19-30`= 1*(age > 18 & age <= 30))


#   age  6-18  19-30
# 1  24    0     1
# 2  10    1     0
# 3  50    0     0
```

Note: `1 *` in mutate is to convert to 0 and 1 from `FALSE` and `TRUE`. You can add additional columns within the mutate function above.